# how to use index match left to right and right to left in this condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to get data of any person on mentioned dated using index formula but always return invalid value. how i am doing this. due to data exportation date always in last column.

What I am doing:  I select person name in a given excel sheet from a drop down(data validation option) and selecting date to show all data against a particular agent on a particular date

For mentioned below data I am using

```
=index(A:E,match(sheet2!A1,A:A,0),Match(sheet2!B1,B:B),Match(sheet2,C1,E:E))
```

always give N/A.

Please help

```
Login ID         ACD Calls  Avg ACD Time    Avg ACW Time    Date
Qayyum              64       :03:10            :00:03      1/5/2017
Abdul               80       :02:56            :00:05      1/3/2017
Abdul               107      :03:07            :00:04      1/4/2017
Abdullah            62       :02:12            :00:02      1/2/2017
Afreen jahan        94       :02:55            :00:07      1/3/2017
Afreen jahan        81       :03:05            :00:08      1/2/2017
```

Sheet2

```
A1                       B1                      C1
Abdul                  ACD Calls              1/2/2017
```

Answer (score 0):

You are providing 3 coordinates to a 2 dimensional area.

When you evaluate the Index function, the Match functions within return `3,3,3`. Excel doesn't know what to do with the extra coordinate.  Excel is expecting `3,3` - third row, third column.

To see the Avg ACD Time based on the Login, Calls and Date, use this formula:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$7,1,SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$7=Sheet2!$A$1),--($B$2:$B$7=Sheet2!$B$1),--($E$2:$E$7=Sheet2!$C$1)))
```

To see the Avg ACW Time based on the Login, Calls and Date, use this formula:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$7,1,SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$7=Sheet2!$A$1),--($B$2:$B$7=Sheet2!$B$1),--($E$2:$E$7=Sheet2!$C$1)))
```

This is indexing the column based on Boolean value for the values on Sheet2 matching the corresponding columns in Sheet1.
If nothing is found, it will return the column header. 
You will need to adjust the formula ranges to match your data range.

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise, `INDEX()` DOES know what to do with the third coordinate and tries to do that.

That "third" (fourth, since the range is the first and `MATCH()` is adding "coordinates" 2, 3, and 4), is the `AREA` parameter.

`INDEX()` allows you to have several areas (ranges) that it will treat individually. They can be contiguous or non-contiguous, EVEN overlapping or duplicated. You tell it which one to process with in the fourth parameter.

In the problem presented here, there is only a single area. So telling `INDEX()` to use the 3rd area fails (the N/A error) because there is no 3rd area to use.

The above is for understanding only. The solution is still to do things differently! You know, by not specifying an `AREA`'s parameter.